# Does anybody know what is the Eclipse-core bugzilla link?

Tags: bugzilla

I'm writing a program to retrieve the bug report for a specified bug ID, I already have the bugID all I need is to know to which link should I query in order to get the report for that bug which would be I think in JSON.
For example:
EclipseBugzilla-link.com?bugID=1234
something like the aforementioned url.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I mean by Eclipse is the eclipse-core projects...

Answer (score 0):

You can use bugzilla's `XMLRPC` mechanism to get an information about a specific bug id. It is fairly easy to use that mechanism. However, the output is, of course, XML.

There are quite a lot of `XMLRPC` libraries for nearly every popular programming languages. You may want to look at your favorite programming language's XMLRPC libraries. For python, there is [bugzilla tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bugzillatools) that supports editing, removing, adding, commenting, and getting bug information.

Comment: I have previously used JIRA for getting bug reports for apache project that seems really easy. For example, with this url https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/BUGID you can get the bug reports isn't there such a URL for bugzilla?

Comment: There is an url for bugzilla, it's `xmlrpc.cgi`, and it's an `XMLRPC` service. You cannot use it by simply visiting an URL. When requesting something from a server, you need to send your query in XMLRPC format. The server will also respond in that format. Please look at wiki for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC

Typically, you will not need to learn data types written in wikipedia. Your XMLRPC library will handle all the low-level stuff and you will be able to get bug information easily. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630095/is-there-a-java-api-to-access-bugzilla

Comment: Ok now I'm using the API can you help me with the URL of bugzilla for eclipse?

Comment: I have given the tool in python in the answer. If we are talking about Eclipse project's bugzilla, it is http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/xmlrpc.cgi. However, I get internal server error when I try to use its service. It's related with eclipse bugzilla.

Comment: Could you please check the answer if you find it useful? :)